# Merging Two iOS Apps

Tags: ios

I have two iOS apps. How I can merge them into one app ?(App A,App B, I want to make an app C which consist app A,B.) Is there any way to call AppDelegate methods of one app in the other app?
I have tried adding the apps as Libraries. But that does not give me the access to the AppDelegate methods. Should I manually merge the code base of two apps?

Comment: What a strange question.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling "AppDelegate methods" from inside an app full stop. Never mind from inside another app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there isn't.

The Application Delegate (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html)) is effectively a application-wide *singleton* and is created by and has specific interactions with the Cocoa Touch framework.

Consequently it is not possible to have multiple AppDelegates, nor does it make sense.   If you want to merge the functionality of two applications, you would likely merge the view, view-controllers and model elements, but have one AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense. Will implement the functionality manually.

Comment: Not effectively a singleton. Just an object that has been set to the delegate of the NSApplication or UIApplication object. ( OSX and ios respectively )

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Objective C programming is not like mixing different paint colors and getting a third one as a result. If I were you, I would rather create a new project and code everything from ground up. There's no such thing as "merging" two projects (apps if you will) into a third one.